# Python Interactive Cmd Question (3 parameters problem)

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I did figure out how to use the Cmd module offered in Python lib, but I am with a trouble now...

Here is the code:

```
def do_addtext(self, file, text = ""):
        "Add text to the end of a file"
        if os.path.exists(file) == True:
            f = open(file, 'a')
            f.write("\n" + text)
            print "\n>>> Text added!\n"
        else:
            print "\n>>> File do not exists\n"
```

It works all fine when I use functions of only two parameters but I am not being able to use it with three parameters.

So it is fine to call a funcion on the command line like "create file.txt" but i cant use this one... "addtext file.txt sometext"

I suppose it does not recognizes there are three different fields?

Any help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I change the name file and removed the == True as well. I have still a problem in making it work via the command line.. it does not recognize the third parameter.

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: this question is unanswerable. how are we supposed to know how the this function is called and what connection it has to command-line parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Cmd object parses the input, it takes the first word and uses that as the function name.  The remainder of the text is passed in as a single parameter.  The do_* functions take only 2 parameters: self and the remainder of the string from the input.  So, if you type:

```
> foo This is my text
```

At the prompt, then cmd will try to call a function self.do_foo("This is my text").  It won't split the string up into separater arguments for you.  That is, it won't try to call self.do_foo("This", "is", "my", "text").

If you want your functions to process more arguments, you'll need to parse the line a bit more on your own.  Right now, you have do_addtext as taking 3 parameters.  So you would have to rewrite do_addtext to have only 2 parameters, something like:

```
do_addtext(self, parameter):
  "Add text to end of file."
  filename,text = parameter.split(" ", 1)  # <--- this does the parsing you wanted Cmd to do
  if os.path.exists(filename) == True:
    f = open(filename, 'a')
    f.write("\n" + text)
    print "\n>>> Text added!\n"
  else:
    print "\n>>> File do not exists\n"
```

Also, see this [wiki on CmdModule](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule).  It has an explanation of the do_xxx methods.

Comment: That's brilliant! Work's just perfectly! Thank you very much!